# Herstein's Chapter 3, supplementary problem 28: polynomial with a non-trivial root mod p for all primes p

Tags: abstract-algebra

Herstein says:

> Construct a polynomial $q(x) \neq 0$ with integer coefficients which
>   has no rational roots but is such that for any prime $p$ we can solve
>   the congruence $q(x) \equiv 0$ mod $p$ in the integers.

I've thought about this a good bit without making any headway at all and, though I presume the answer is already on this site somewhere, I haven't found it.  Solutions, hints, pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the polynomial $q(x) = (x^{2} - 2)(x^{2} - 3)(x^{2} - 6)$ has a root modulo $p$ for every prime $p$ but has no root in $\mathbb{Q}$. We will show that one of the three numbers $2,3,6$ is a square. There is a number theoretic fact that says the product of two non-squares is a square, but we will just stick to a group theory argument.

If $p =2$ then all three numbers involved are squares. Suppose $p$ is odd. Consider the map $\phi: \mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}: x \mapsto x^{2}$. 
Since  $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ is commutative, the map is a homomorphism of groups. $\ker \phi = \{ \pm 1 \} \implies [\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}: \text{Im}\ \phi] = 2$, which implies that the quotient group $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}/\text{Im}\ \phi$ is a group of order 2 so that every square in it is identity, namely $\text{Im}\ \phi$.

Suppose now that $2$ and $3$ were not squares, then $2, 3 \notin \text{Im}\ \phi$, but since the coset consists of two elements we must then have $2 \text{Im}\ \phi = 3 \text{Im}\ \phi \implies \text{Im}\ \phi = 2 \text{Im}\ \phi \cdot 2\text{Im}\ \phi = 2\text{Im}\ \phi \cdot 3\text{Im}\ \phi = 6 \text{Im}\ \phi$, which implies that $6 \in \text{Im}\ \phi$ so that it is a square. Now the right hand side of the original equation is seen to have a root modulo $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q(x) = (x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)(x^2 - 6)$.  There are no rational roots, but at least one of $2,3,6$ is a square modulo any prime.